# How to pass two option values to PHP

Tags: php, html-select

Below is the code I currently have and it is working on passing `week_num`. I am using `session_start()` to pass my variables from page to page.

```
print'<form action="changeplayer_2.php" method="post">';

print"<select name='Week_select'> <br>";

while ($wrow=mysql_fetch_array($wresult)){ 
     print '<option value="'.$wrow['week_num'].'">'.'week '.$wrow['week_num'].' 
     '.$wrow['week_name'].'</option><br>\n';    
}

print "</select><br><br>";
```

What I am curious about is whether or not I can also pass `week_name` to the next page.
Please keep in mind that I am still a beginner so I would appreciate anything you could tell me about why/how a fix will work.

I have tried

```
print '<option value="'.$wrow['week_num,week_name'].'">'.'week '.$wrow['week_num'].'     '.$wrow['week_name'].'</option><br>\n';
```

and

```
print '<option value="'.$wrow['week_num','week_name'].'">'.'week '.$wrow['week_num'].'     '.$wrow['week_name'].'</option><br>\n';
```

both of which generate errors

Comment: week number makes sense, but when did the 52 weeks get names?

Comment: try splitting your variable from $wrow['week_num','week_name'] to $wrow['week_num'].$wrow['week_name']

Comment: @dagon the week name is in the DB as 16 April 2013, 9 April 2013....

Comment: @Last Breath   Ok both this and shodev's worked...almost. Now the value shows up as 1 single string... How do I get them as separate variables?

Comment: as its a one to one relationship you don't need to send both you can generate or look it up as needed, bast not to parse more data than needed around

Comment: @Dagon Good point. All you really need to know is the `week_num`. You can look up the `week_name` in the database using the number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this concatenation:

```
print '<option value="'.$wrow['week_num'].'_'.$wrow['week_name'].'">'.'week '.$wrow['week_num'].'     '.$wrow['week_name'].'</option><br>\n';
```

Comment: Ok both this and Last Breath's worked...almost. Now the value shows up as 1 single string... How do I get them as separate variables?

Comment: Using this method, you'll need to split them into an array with PHP after submission using `explode()`. Something like `explode('_',$Week_Select)`.

Comment: OK something else to learn :) So in order to use the explode, I need to use the underscore as you have it and not Last Breath's

Comment: First of all if is your status i think that the concatenation way of [showdev] is more proper than mine then after using this concatenation using the '_'
you must get this as 1 variable then split them into 2 variables inside the php page that will recieve this data by explooding the value

If you need explanaition tell me

Comment: Last Breath's solution will concatenate the values like this: "16April 2013". This is more difficult to explode, but not impossible. I suggest using a separating character to make it easier (e.g. underscore).

Comment: OK finding out a bit on the basics of explode. let me try playing around. I assume I need to explode on the page 2?

Comment: Yes, use explode on the page to which you are submitting. You could do something like this: `list($week_num,$week_name)=explode("_",$_POST['Week_select']);` Might want to modify it for better error checking, but that's the general idea.

Comment: yes exactly the explode method will split any string into arrays due a splitting chars look like this :
$var1 = "My_Name_Is_Last_Breath";
$newarr = explode('_',$var1);

Then the $newarr will have this structure now :
array("My","Name","Is","Last","Breath")

So that's it my string value has been splitted into array due the explode method and that what you need inside your second php page that will process the recieved data from your form @Bill Flippen

Comment: ran with it before I saw your comments, Came up with : `SESSION_START(); $_SESSION['Week_select']=$_POST['Week_select']; $week=explode('_',$_SESSION['Week_select']); $varWeek=$week[0]; $varWeekName=$week[1]; echo $_SESSION['Week_select']; echo $varWeek; echo $varWeekName;` doesn't want to work....will try the list.

Comment: That seems like it would work. Using `list` was just an example -- there are many methods of juggling that data. Make sure your variable is being posted correctly and that your session is working properly. Try `print_r($_POST['Week_select'])` to see the structure of the posted variable.

Comment: So I even tried this `SESSION_START(); $_SESSION['Week_select']=$_POST['Week_select']; list($varWeek,$varWeekName)=explode('_',$_SESSION['Week_select']); print "<br>"; #$varWeek=$week[0]; #$varWeekName=$week[1]; echo $_SESSION['Week_select']; #echo $varWeek; print "<br>"; echo $varWeekName;` I see `12013-02-12 Select a team that played season 12 and week ` the exploded parts arent; coming through. 1 is the week number 2013-02-12 is the name and as you can see those are being displayed in the conc form

Comment: I will do a little more research in to this, and if neede will post a new question pertaining to explode as not to derail this topic. Thanks guys!